# Mixed tensor macro for TeXstudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, tensor

As the title says, I'm looking for a mixed tensor macro for TeXstudio. For example, if I want to get `M \indices{^a_b^{cd}_e}` (using the tensor package), I would like to type `M.T{uduud}{a,b,c,d,e}`, the trigger being of the form `.T{ud...d}{a,b ... e}`, to obtain the same. The `.T` stands for converting the preceding character to a mixed tensor, while `u/d` stands for if the index is an up index (contravariant) or down index (covariant). Needless to say, I would like this to handle multiple indices as given in the first argument. I believe I need a script to do this.

Additional: To complete the notation, it would be great if it can handle both up and down indices at the same position. For example, `.T{**}{i,j}`would give `^{i}_{j}` (first index being a superscript and the second being a subscript, or the other way is also completely fine)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this (really) specific to TeXstudio?

Comment: By macros, I'm referring to the custom macros one can build inside TeXstudio and not the `\def` or `\newcommand`. But the latter works too, no issues. It is just that I have all my macros inside TeXstudio.

Comment: if you are looking at editor shorthands not tex macros you should really edit your question to make that a _lot_ clearer, I probably would not even have noticed the texstudio tag (handling the `{uuddd}`  in a tex macro wouldn't be that hard, but handling a suffix `.T` notation in TeX would be quite a lot harder.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I was looking for something along the lines of `editor.write()` because that's how all my other things are. For example, I've `([\\]?[A-Za-z]+)\.t\ ` as a trigger and the action is `editor.write("\\dot{" + triggerMatches[1] + "}")` for producing a dotted character. I know this isn't the best way to do this, but it works for me for the time being.